I'm trying to make post requests to Firebase URL but it's giving a 400 error
I'm trying to make post requests to the Firebase Auth REST API, at the following url: httpss://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[my key]
but I'm getting the following error in my console after trying to login:

Http failure response for
httpss://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyDThl5AbjP3GU4XvtdpBn5ZvVUFVXMJMSA: 400 OK

my login method to the service
login(data: any): Observable<UserAuth>{
  console.log(data)
  var url: string = this.FIREBASE_URL + 'v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=' +
  this.TOKEN_FIREBASE
  console.log(url)
  return this.segurancaHttp.post<UserAuth>(url, data, httpOptions)
}

my login.component method
onSubmit(): void {
  if (this.autorizacaoService.obterLoginStatus()) {
    this.autorizacaoService.deslogar()
  } else {
    this.service.login(this.addressForm.value).subscribe({  
      
      next: (response) => {
         console.log(response.idToken)
         if(response.idToken){
          this.autorizacaoService.autorizar(response.idToken)

          this.route.navigate(['/usuario'])
         }
       
      },
      error: (erro: any) => { 
        console.log(erro)
        alert('Ocorreu algum erro')
      }
    })
  }
}

I am using version 17 of Angular.

What does the data you are sending, contain? Is this code making a request with Content-Type: application/json, as it is supposed to? Have you checked what the response body contained?

yes, I'm using Content-Type: application/json. the data refers to my object, I am printing its values ​​in the console. @c3roe

HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts…sword?key=AIzaSyDThl5AbjP3GU4XvtdpBn5ZvVUFVXMJMSA', ok: false, …}
error
:
{error: {…}}
headers
:
_HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure response for https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyDThl5AbjP3GU4XvtdpBn5ZvVUFVXMJMSA: 400 OK"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
400
statusText
:
"OK"

Can't tell from that, if there might be more info hiding in any of the ... parts.

which part of the code would you like to analyze? @C3roe

Mainly asking about this part, error : {error: {…}}, if there's any more info in there, when you fully expand it.

(Google is really giving 400 OK as response status? Weird.)

errors
:
Array(1)
0
:
{message: 'INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS', domain: 'global', reason: 'invalid'}
length
:
1
[[Prototype]]
:
Array(0)
message
:
"INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS"   this is the message contained within the array @C3roe

is "httpss:" just a typo in your post?

btw, looks like you're trying to pass a value as a GET there, but their docs say to send as body of request... (probably a POST?): https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithPassword
